# Choose interpolation nodes

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

How to determine power of interpolation polynomial and interpolation nodes so this polynomial approximates function $y = 2 * sin(3x)$ at $[0,1]$ with estimate error less or equal to $0.2$ ? 
How should I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

**hint $$

if $f (x)=2\sin (3x) $ then

$f^{n+1}(x)=2. (3^{n+1})\sin (3x+(n+1)\frac {\pi}{2}) $
and
$$|f^{n+1}(x)|\leq 2. (3^{n+1}) $$

the error $E $ is given by

$$E(x)=\frac {\prod_{i=0}^n (x-x_i)}{(n+1)!}f^{n+1}(\xi) $$

and you should have
$$|E (x)|\leq 0.2.$$
or
$$\frac {3^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\leq 0.1$$
using the fact that $|x-x_i|\leq 1$.

Comment: how did you get first formula ? $$f^{n+1}(x)=2. (3^n)\sin (3x+n\frac {\pi}{2})$$

Comment: It is known that $\sin^{(n)}(x)=\sin (x+n\frac \pi 2$. at each derivative you add pi/2  and multiply by 3.